# Add quotation mark in VB.NET string

Tags: string, concatenation, vb.net-2010

I am struggling with this:

I have this:

```
Dim nam as String = "my name is John Scott"
Dim fn As String = "James"
```

I would like to replace it to:

```
nam = "my name is " & fn & " Scott"
```

I have tried this:

```
nam = nam.Replace("John", """" & fn & """")
```

But that is giving me:

```
nam = "my name is "" & fn & "" Scott".
```

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: What do you expect when you write nam = nam.Replace("John", """" & fn & """")

Comment: I want to add a quotation mark around the firstname (fn). If I supply      "my name is " & fn & " Scott" then I will not get the quotation mark. To escape the quotation mark I have supplied      """" & fn & """", which unfortunately places 2 of them! I need just one on the left and on the right of fn...

Comment: you want something like I am "James" Scott?

Comment: Yes, exactly! contained in a string variable called "nam". So when I say NameTextBox.Text = nam, I see [ I am "James" Scott ]. The names in quotation marks are like Nicknames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1:

```
Module Module1
        Sub Main()
            Dim nam As String = "my name is John Scott"
            Dim fn As String = "James"
            nam = "my name is """ & fn & """ Scott"
            MsgBox(nam)
        End Sub
End Module
```

Method 2:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim nam As String = "my name is John Scott"
        Dim fn As String = "James"
        fn = """" & fn & """"
        nam = "my name is " & fn & " Scott"
        MsgBox(nam)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thanks. I was pre-occupied with reading the code lines without making an output, yet. The msgbox part does show it works.

Answer (score 0):

OR use this method

```
Dim fn As String = "James" CHR(34) &
```